# oracle materialized view deleting data if master table changed

Tags: java, oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

First time writing materialized views. I created a materialized view like below with materialized view log.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON table1 WITH SEQUENCE, ROWID, PRIMARY KEY INCLUDING NEW VALUES;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON table2  WITH SEQUENCE, ROWID, PRIMARY KEY INCLUDING NEW VALUES;


    create materialized view test_hosp_mv
         refresh fast on commit
       as
    select h.hid, h.hospital_name, h.rowid h_rowid, hho.rowid hho_rowid from table1 h, table2 hho
    where h.hid = hho.hid
    and h.status = 'Approved'
    and hho.flag = 'Y'
    order by hid desc
```

materialized view created successfully and inserted all records to the mv. The problem is when status changes to unapproved in the master table(table1) ie. h.status = 'Unapproved', the data is deleting from materialized view. sorry for ineptitude, but can i stop deleting data from materialized view?

Comment: Why would you want to?  If you didn't remove the row, the data in the materialized view would no longer match the data returned by the query.  That doesn't make sense.  Are you sure that you don't want to change the logic in the query so that, say, you return everything where the status has ever been Approved (assuming you have a history table that tells you that).

Comment: justin, our requirement is like that. Ie. Only insert/update the data in the materialized view when status is "Approved".  If not approved, then dont insert to materialized view. Any solutions? To be more clear, Application 1 inserts data in application 1 database, and we take the consolidated data to materialized view and supply to Application 2. (based on the condition status = Approved)

Comment: It sounds like a materialized view is the wrong approach if you can't alter the query to return the data you want.  What happens if someone in the future decides to do a full refresh of the materialized view?  That's going to truncate and reload.